# Change jquery function on click

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I wrote a function to change the height of container according to its content

```
function heightChange()
{
var h1 = $("#primary-page .entry-content-pageAbout").height();
var h2 = 550;
var max = Math.max(h1,h2);
$('#content').height(max);
}
```

and it works on `$(window).resize`

i want to change the height on click, so i wrote this

```
$(".entry-content-sublinksAbout a:eq(0)").click(function(){
$(".entry-content-page-holder").animate({top:-420}, 800,'easeInOutCubic');
heightChange();
});
```

my problem is on click i want to get the function and also want to deduct the `top:-420` from the total height of `#content`it which i just animated on click.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I'm unsure what you're asking for here, but is this something that will help?

```
function heightChange(a) {
    $(".entry-content-page-holder").animate({top:-420}, 800,'easeInOutCubic');
    var h1 = $("#primary-page .entry-content-pageAbout").height();
    var h2 = 550;
    var h3 = a;
    var max = Math.max(h1,h2);
    max = max - h3;
    $('#content').height(max);
}

$(".entry-content-sublinksAbout a:eq(0)").click(function(){
    heightChange(420);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    heightChange(0);
});
```